# hyperbola curve formula in 3 dimensions

Tags: conic-sections, 3d

Cartesian formula for 2d hyperbola curve is $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2 = 1$.

What is the formula for a 3d hyperbola curve?

Comment: Are you looking for a curve or a surface?

Comment: I need the curve, NOT a surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is a 3D hyperbola curve?  How about $\frac {x^2}{a^2}-\frac {y^2}{b^2}=1, z=0$.  If you want a curve in 3D, you need two equations, just like a line.  I suspect this is not what you want, so please explain.

Alternately, you might want $\frac {x^2}{a^2}-\frac {y^2+z^2}{b^2}=1$, which is a surface that rotates the 2D curve around the $x$ axis.

Added in response to comment:  Given your three points, you can solve for the $a,b,c$ that are the equation of the plane.  Be careful-we have been using $a,b$ as parameters of the hyperbola and now you are reusing them.  The $m$ in my previous comment corresponds to $\frac ba$ here, but my plane went through the $z$ axis while if $c \ne 0$ it will miss the $z$ axis by that much.
A hyperbola with its axis parallel to $z$ that is in the plane $ax+by=0$ is $\frac {z^2}{d^2}-\frac {x^2+y^2}{e^2}=1,y=-\frac ba x$  To get it into the plane $ax+by=c$ we add $\frac c{\sqrt {1+(\frac ab)^2}}$ to $x$ and $\frac ab\frac c{\sqrt {1+(\frac ab)^2}}$ to $y$ giving $$\left\{(x',y',z)\left|\frac {z^2}{d^2}-\frac {x^2+y^2}{e^2}=1,y=-\frac ba x,x'=x+,y'=y+\frac ab\frac c{\sqrt {1+(\frac ab)^2}}\right.\right\}$$

Comment: I really need a curve, sir. The example you have given is for a curve that is laying on a z=0 plane, but the ones I need does not. Can you give a more generic formula? If here are many, could you give a formula that is for the curves laying on a planes which are parallel to Z-axis?

Comment: @Reef you can pick any plane that includes the $x$ axis and intersect it with the rotated surface I gave.  Basically you plot $\frac {x^2}{a^2}-\frac {y^2}{b^2}=1$, but then instead of $(x,y,0)$ you plot $(x,\pm\frac 1{\sqrt 1+m^2}y,\pm\frac m{\sqrt 1+m^2}y)$ for your favorite $m$.  The signs need to match, but $m$ could be negative.  This gives you the same curve in a tilted plane.  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: @Reef:  A plane that is parallel to the $z$ axis is $x=c$.  We can then plot $\frac {z^2}{a^2}-\frac {y^2}{b^2}=1, x=c$.  You can do the same thing in $y$ or rotated in between.

Comment: This looks like it could be what I need, but I have some trouble understanding it. Could you give an example of that (for a non-trivial m) in Wolfram Alpha or some other tool? If I understand correctly, any ax+by=c is a plane parallel to the z axis. In my case hyperbola has 3 known points on some unknown ax+by=c plane. If I had a formula for 3d hyperbola, I could solve a system of 3(?) equations to get coefficients for hyperbola going through my points (which is what I need to do).

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by a "3d hyperbola curve"?

If you really mean a curve, something like
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1 \\ z= 0 \end{cases}$$
is one example. (There are others.)

If you mean the "3d version" you get hyperboloids of one and two sheets respectively, but these are surfaces, not curves:

$x^2+y^2-z^2 = 1$ [image: $x^2+y^2-z^2 = 1$]

$x^2-y^2-z^2 = 1$ [image: $x^2-y^2-z^2 = 1$]

Notice that these surfaces are obtained by rotating a planar hyperbola around one of its two lines of symmetry.

Comment: I really, really need a curve. The example you have given is for a curve that is laying on a z=0 plane, but the ones I need does not. Can you give a more generic formula? If here are many, could you give a formula that is for the curves laying on a planes which are parallel to Z-axis?

Answer (score 0):

Write your hyperbola on z=0 plane. Then apply shifting the origin and rotating around all three axis. You should multiply your (x,y,z) vector by a 3x3 matrix for rotations in one step.